# How to use typekit font in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to use typekit font in ionic 3 for both of ios and android.

Is it possible? then, how?

Also, I have cloud font icons which needs to be imported, as well.

but my concern is that what if we lost a connection? all icons and fonts will be broken?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Download the font files and use them as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340925/google-fonts-in-ionic-2

Comment: You can't https://helpx.adobe.com/typekit/using/font-licensing.html#sync-app